# Add Padding Underneath the Facebook Comments Plugin

Tags: comments, padding, facebook-comments

I want to add the Facebook Comments app on my site, which I was able to do successfully. However, how would I add a 10 pixel padding under the comments box? The code I paseted to my site is listed below.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try

```
<div style="padding-bottom:10px" class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
```

As CSS inject to the div tag. It might need a ; after pixels

Equally ad an 'id' to it in the CSS sheet that gives it the parameters you want